# Error when uploading file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I have an `ASP.NET` application hosted on `brinkster`. It was running smoothly before, one day I got error when opening connection to `MS Access database`. I tried `impersonate = "false"` in my `web config`. And the problem was resolved but a new problem started. I am not able to upload any image in any folder in my application. If I remove `impersonate= "false"` or add `impersonate="true"` it is giving previous error on opening connection. `ASP.NET` user has full permission.

Do anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to permission of folder where you uploading. You need to give permission of your application pool identity user. Change your application pool of IIS to network service. It will resolve your error.

If you don't have rights to change application pool rights. Try some thing like below.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="network service"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Jalpesh, I tried the above code Now it is giving following error: Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Comment: Then there is no option then changing your application pool identity to network service.

Comment: I contacted to the support guy he is saying that that the user has full permission.

Comment: Ask your support guy to add one user to windows give particular user that permissions and then write identity code in your web.config file.